# Sorting pandas groupby output

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, group-by

I have a dataframe that looks like

```
name   performance   year
bob      50          2002
bob      90          2005
bob      82          2010
joey     50          2015
joey     85          2013
joey     37          1990
sarah    90          1994
sarah    95          2020
sarah    35          2013
```

I would like groupby `name` and compute average `performance` while only displaying the top two results in descending order by performance.

I am currently doing `df.groupby(['name']).mean()` but this computes the averages of both `performance` as well as `year` while displaying all 3 names in alphabetical order (I would only like to display the top 2 in descending order by performance avg).

Comment: `df.groupby('name')['performance'].mean().sort_values(ascending=False).head(2)`  maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is my solution, basically was missing one field in the group by method.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

# defining columns
cols = ['name', 'performance', 'year']

# defining data
data = [
    ['bob',   50, 2002]
,   ['bob',   90, 2005]
,   ['bob',   82, 2010]
,   ['joey',  50, 2015]
,   ['joey',  85, 2013]
,   ['joey',  37, 1990]
,   ['sarah', 90, 1994]
,   ['sarah', 95, 2020]
,   ['sarah', 35, 2013]
]

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)

# dataframe, grouped by name and year, aggregated by mean() of performance, first 2 values in descending order
df = df.groupby(['name', 'year'])['performance'].mean().sort_values(ascending=False).head(2)

# resetting index to display performance column name
df = df.reset_index()

# print dataframe
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    name  year  performance
0  sarah  2020         95.0
1    bob  2005         90.0
```